# После закрытия Putty звершается фоновый процесс

Tags: linux, putty

Вызываю команду: `node мой путь/index.js&` все запускается и выдает ID процесса, но если же закрываю окно Putty то процесс завершается, в чем может быть проблема? Запускаю вроде с фоновом режиме, в конце есть `&`

Comment: господи **фоновый**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В фоне **текущей сессии**. Как только сессия завершается, все её процессы, включая фоновые, завершаются.

Самый простой способ: запустить через GNU Screen или tmux, сессия в котором не зависит от SSH-соединения.

Если без дополнительных средств — нужно отвязать запущенный процесс от его родительского процесса: *демонизировать* его.

**А совсем по-хорошему**: сделать из процесса службу, за которой будет следить ОС-специфичный механизм или другая служба в ОС (какой-нибудь process supervisor): запускать при старте, перезапускать при падении или по запросу.